# Equivalent to shorthandintro=false for biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am using `biblatex-chicago` for my citations in a `memoir` document, thus:

```
\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

While I need my references with a `shorthand` field to behave normally, i.e. citing the full reference in the first instance and using the shorthand in subsequent citations, I don't want any sort of "henceforth cited as..." mention with the first instance. I understand the some `biblatex` styles, such as `philosophy`, allow a `shorthandintro=false` option, but this gives an error in `biblatex-chicago`.

Is there an equivalent way to turn off this behavior across the board for `chicago`, or a way to create such an equivalent? Failing that, is there any way to use the `shorthandintro` field to override each instance (or redefine the shorthandintro globally)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option as far as I can see, but you can easily redefine the macro responsible for the shorthand intro (`cms:shorthandintro`) to do nothing.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes, shorthandibid, backend=biber,
  addendum=false, sorting=nyt, giveninits=true, useprefix=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewbibmacro*{cms:shorthandintro}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite{kant:kpv}
dolor\autocite{sigfridsson}
sit\autocite{kant:kpv}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: I. Kant, ‘Kritik der praktischen Vernunft’, in Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft, vol. 5 of Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe (Berlin: Walter de Gruyter, 1968), 1–163.]

As you can see, footnote 2 does not mention "KpV". Of course that shows the drawback of this method. Your reader will have no idea what "KpV" is even if they have read all the references up to this one.

As [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton) pointed out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482083/equivalent-to-shorthandintro-false-for-biblatex-chicago/482099#comment1218586_482099) a list of shorthands produced by

```
\printbiblist{shorthand}
```

might be a very good idea to make it easier for the reader to resolve the shorthand. I think a list of shorthands makes sense even if you have shorthand intros on first citations, because the reader then has a central place to go to for the shorthands and does not need to hunt down the first citation of a work.

Comment: At least in biblical studies it's common not to use the intro and instead have a list of abbreviations. For SBL style (similar to chicago) most abbreviations are even specified in their handbook.

Comment: @DavidPurton Ah yes, `\printbiblist{shorthand}` is a very good idea. And probably also useful even if one has a shorthand intro, because that does not require a reader to chase down the first mention of a citation.